# ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/users/sign_out"): rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I unable to fixed this error. The error comes when I click my logout button while in production on heroku. However, it works in development. Here is my code

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
<li><%= link_to "Log out",  destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %></li>
 <% else %>
 <li><%= link_to "Sign in", new_user_session_path %></li>
 <% end%>
```

Routes:

```
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#new                                                                                                                                             
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#create                                                                                                                                          
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy                                                                                                                                         
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#create                                                                                                                                         
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)  devise/passwords#new                                                                                                                                            
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#edit                                                                                                                                           
                         PATCH  /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update                                                                                                                                         
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update                                                                                                                                         
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)        devise/registrations#cancel                                                                                                                                     
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#create                                                                                                                                     
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)       devise/registrations#new                                                                                                                                        
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)          devise/registrations#edit                                                                                                                                       
                         PATCH  /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update                                                                                                                                     
                         PUT    /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update                                                                                                                                     
                         DELETE /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#destroy
```

Comment: Please post your entire `application.html.erb` and Heroku log.

Comment: Error fixed - with the following code.
    Fixed with routes.rb add
    devise_scope :user do
    get '/users/sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy'
    end

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is an asset precompilation issue. When you were working, you locally, you ran asset precompilation. When you deployed to Heroku, you now have older files in your public/assets directory, but you didn't run asset precompilation since making further changes to the site and re-deploying to Heroku.

You can either run the asset pre-compilation again locally:

`RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`

Or remove the public/assets directory, commit and redeploy so that Heroku.

Please read here for more references and possible further troubleshooting help: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-4-asset-pipeline